# How to create a subdomain in localhost xampp?

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, subdomain, redirect

I am working on my localhost (xampp). My URL of current directory is `localhost/pms/`. After login of User (with username `XYZ`), I want my URL to become `localhost/XYZ.pms/`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello mate , what you are asking is not exactly subdomain , its typically a path . Understand clearly that  both "pms" and karan.pms" is folders in your case. the domain is localhost . What is possible was you can either make a virtual host entry for http://pms.com to direct to localhost/pms  or http://karan.pms.com to direct to localhost/pms/karan or to localhost/karan or wherever you wish  or http://karan.localhost to some path you wish in local . if any of these is your requirement then update me i will post the answer mate

Comment: Also can you explain that "What do you mean by after login" here ?

Comment: thanks for the reply - i have login page in the index.php when user sucessfully login i just want his name in the url---localhost/pms/ after raja gopal login with its username and password the url become localhost/Raja.pms in this case and rediret its to some other page

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong . DO you mean , if username is xyz and he login then the url should rewrite to localhost/xyz.pms wright?